# Is it valid to solve an equation for multiple coefficients, then average them to obtain overall effect?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, intercept, ecology

I have a regression model, the setup for which is as follows: I am using manyglm, a multivariate general linear model approach to determine the difference in several invertebrate species between two habitats, and also if there is an interaction with habitat and time of day. However, because manyglm cannot take random effects, and my samples span six sites and two seasons, I have included site and season as fixed effects.

So, my model looks like this:

```
species abundance matrix ~ Habitat + Time + Season + Site.letter + Habitat:Time
```

(the levels of each variable, all of which are categorical, are below):

```
Habitat: factor with two levels (Litter and Log)
Time:  factor with two levels (Day and Night)
Site factor with six levels (D, G, H, K, L, N)
Season: factor with two levels (Spring, Autumn)
```

I then run an ANOVA that tests if each variable and interaction is significant overall. I can then run a comparison which lets me know which species are significantly affected by each variable. This part is not complicated: I can know, for instance, that Litter and Log are significantly different, and that this is due to species x, y and z. What this does not answer is if species x higher in abundance in the litter, rather than the logs. This is my research question: I want to know what species are different between litter and logs, and in what direction (higher in litter than logs?).

To do that, and to show the difference graphically where predictors are significant,  between litter and logs, for instance, I was going to plot the coefficients for each. It is here that I run into problems. Take the coefficients for one species below:

```
                                                              Amphipoda 
(Intercept)                                                 -3.06
HabitatLog                                                   0.27 
TimeNight                                                   -0.38 
SiteG                                                        1.10 
SiteH                                                       -0.09 
SiteK                                                        1.05 
SiteL                                                       -1.05 
SiteN                                                      -12.65 
SeasonSpring                                                 1.69  
HabitatLog:TimeNight                                         0.43
```

In an ordinary model, I could add coefficients together to obtain the effect for various combinations of predictor variables. So, to obtain the effect of logs in the daytime I would add the coefficient "HabitatLog" to the Intercept. However, the intercept doesn't actually represent simply the effect for Litter during the Day; it represents the effect for Litter in Autumn at site D during the day. (this, btw, was cleared up in this related question here: [Interpreting intercept in multivariate linear regression when excluding some factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389667/interpreting-intercept-in-multivariate-linear-regression-when-excluding-some-fac/))

So, I cannot actually obtain a coefficient for just the effect of Litter (or logs) during the day. (This problem is created because I cannot include random effects, but still wish to account for spatial and temporal variation in the data.)

Unless... I solve the equation Litter during the day, for each site during each season, obtaining a total of twelve coefficients, which I then average, to obtain an overall effect (this assumes that each site and season contributes equally to the model, which I think is a safe assumption with my data). So this is my question: is the approach in the previous sentence legitimate or is it problematic in any way?

For example:

```
Litter Day Autumn at site
D = -3.06          (intercept or beta0) = -3.06
G = -3.06 + 1.09   (beta0 + beta4)      = -1.96
H = -3.06 + -0.08  (beta0 + beta6)      = -3.15
K = -3.06 + 1.04   (beta0 + beta7)      = -2.01
L = -3.06 + -1.04  (beta0 + beta8)      = -4.11
N = -3.06 + -12.65 (beta0 + beta9)      = -15.71

Litter Day Spring at site
as above except that we add beta10 (1.69) to each of the above numbers
D = -3.06  + 1.69 ((beta0) + beta10)         = -1.37
G = -1.96  + 1.69 ((beta0 + beta4) + beta10) = -0.27
H = -3.15  + 1.69 ((beta0 + beta6) + beta10) = -1.46
K = -2.01  + 1.69 ((beta0 + beta7) + beta10) = -0.32
L = -4.11  + 1.69 ((beta0 + beta8) + beta10) = -2.42
N = -15.71 + 1.69 ((beta0 + beta9) + beta10) = -14.02
```

The average of these twelve numbers is -4.16, which represents the average coeffient for Litter during the day, over all sites and seasons. Or is this completely wrong?

Comment: You might consider taking the median value rather than the mean value.

Comment: That's true, especially since one coefficient is three times as high as any other.